# https://cloudsearch.googleapis.com/v1:initializeCustomer throws 400 error

Tags: google-cloud-search

Receive the below error when trying to enable 3rd party support for google cloud search.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 163
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
- -content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2023 22:54:54 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
   "error": {
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\ncurl --request POST \n^", 
     "code": 400
   }
 }
```

Tried various changes to how the access code was formatted.